# How to use position method in % in HTML/CSS to adjust to monitor resolution with more precision?

Tags: html, css, position, screen, resolution

In my program, I need to place the image of a button on top of another image exactly where that button is supposed to be. To be able to use it in different monitor resolution, I position the images using %. I also set up height and width of the body (or div) to 100vw and 100vh (i also tried to screen.height and window.height). But when I change resolution of the monitor, the images adjust to the new resolution but now with enough precision y the height (width is fine). The button is displayed a little bit higher in a lower resolution. Why is not working?

```css
.alarm img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 4.5%;
  left: 41.7%;
  top: 71%;
}

.faceplate img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 17%;
  left: 40%;
  top: 40%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body style="width:100vw; height:100vh; margin:0;padding:0">
  <div_logo class="faceplate"><img src="pictures/asel3_faceplate.png">

    <div_alarm class="alarm"><img src="pictures/asel3_alarm.png"></div_alarm>

  </div_logo>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: try with `vw` & `vh` like `left:40vw` & `top:70vh`

Comment: @lalji Tadhani adding top:70vh; doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use media queries to fix this problem for different screen sizes. You have to create different types of CSS for different types of screen sizes.

In this fact, you have to go to media queries.

For more details, you can follow the link

1. https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp

In media, query defines your CSS style for different screen sizes.

Comment: I'm placing lots of images that have to have a relative position to other images. Does it mean I have to set up the relative position of all images for 3-4 different resolutions image by image with the media queries? isn't there a more global solution?

Comment: sorry boss you must go for a media query, if you don't want to do that by using media query you should go for bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are expecting.

```
.faceplate {
  top:25%;  /* just change this */
  left:25%; /* just change this */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.faceplate {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}

.faceplate > img {
  width: 90%;
  height:90%;
}

.faceplate .alarm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.faceplate .alarm > img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="faceplate"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/e055e0/fff">

    <div class="alarm"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need to use % instead of px as I need both the size and the position to be relative to monitor resolution. If I use px, the image will look bigger in a monitor with a smaller resolution

Comment: changing to body position relative; images position absolute and keeping the percentages I get the same results. the image alarm still higher at a lower resolution